# Evento mouse Qlabel desde otro objeto

Tags: c++, qt

Tengo un objeto tipo A y cuando lo inicio creo un objeto tipo grid y dentro de este grid estoy creando unos 100 Qlabel.

He creado un evento mouse para cuando haga click en el objeto Qlabel se me inicie este evento.

Me gustaría que el evento mouse de los Qlabel se iniciara en el objeto A y me devolviera el objeto pulsado, por ejemplo me devolveria el objeto Qlabel(45). Tendría que gestionar los eventos desde su creador.

¿Es posible hacer esto?

Comment: I am using a Qwidget not a MainWindow

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar un filtro de eventos para los labels. En tu caso el filtro de eventos puede ser el propio objeto `A`:

```
class A : public QObject
{
private:

  bool eventFilter(QObject *object, QEvent *event) override
  {
    if( event->type() == QEvent::MousePress)
    {
      QMouseEvent* mouseEvent = static_cast<QMouseEvent*>(event);
      // ... 
    }
  }
};
```

Para que el filtro actúe es necesario *instalarlo* en los `QLabel`:

```
A a;

QLabel * label = new QLabel;
label->installEventFilter(&a);
```